# Why is my Android app saying Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute on Android St

Tags: android

So I am making this GPS app which shows nearby locations and here is my code for MapsActivity.java:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location lastLocation;
private Marker currentLocationMarker;
public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Button btnRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRestaurant);
    btnRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String Restaurant = "restaurant";
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
            mMap.clear();
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
            Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
            DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            DataTransfer[1] = url;
            Log.d("onClick", url);
            GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Button btnHospital = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHospital);
    btnHospital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String Hospital = "hospital";
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
            mMap.clear();
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Hospital);
            Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
            DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            DataTransfer[1] = url;
            Log.d("onClick", url);
            GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Hospitals", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Button btnSchool = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSchool);
    btnSchool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String School = "school";
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
            mMap.clear();
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, School);
            Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
            DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            DataTransfer[1] = url;
            Log.d("onClick", url);
            GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Schools", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
    private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }





@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //permission is granted
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(client != null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            else //permission is denied
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
    }
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
   client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .addApi(LocationServices.API)
           .build();

   client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;

    if(currentLocationMarker !=null)
    {
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Location");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));

    if(client != null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);

}
private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyATA3OL5hATOCnGWY8INWycPhND6bIp-BU");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}


public boolean checkLocationPermission(){

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
       if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
       {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
       }
       else
       {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
       }
       return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

and here is my code for the activity_maps.xml file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
tools:context="com.neilgmail.mita.icanemapp211.MapsActivity">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:text="Nearby Schools"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now comes my problem. When I am running the app on my phone it is saying Unfortunately, Map has stopped. I ran the debugger on the log-cat for Android Studio and this is the specific error message which is coming up: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
These are my imports on the maps activity if you need them

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding a fragment without a layout like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
tools:context="com.neilgmail.mita.icanemapp211.MapsActivity">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp">
   ...
</FrameLayout>
```

You must put the fragment inside a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.neilgmail.mita.icanemapp211.MapsActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp">

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_width="75dp">
               ...
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where do the buttons go?

Comment: Inside the FrameLayout like you previous layout. replace the `...` with your previous view.